# Plotting a live graph of a CSV. (Using only certain values inside the CSV)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, plot

My question is: How can I fix this code, so that it plots

```
DID
```

and

```
Value
```

I am getting an Error that states "'Series Object has no attribute 'Find''"

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.read_csv('CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv').T.to_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv' , header=False)

df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv', skiprows = 2)

DID = df['SN']
Value = df['26']

x= (DID[16:21])
y= (Value[15:21])

print(x,y)


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

and here is the Output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/eric.bell/Desktop/NB Graphing Data Analysis/Transposing_Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/eric.bell/Desktop/NB Graphing Data Analysis')
16    35
17    36
18    37
19    38
20    39
Name: SN, dtype: object 15    60
16     1
17     1
18     1
19     1
20     1
Name: 26, dtype: object


File "C:\Users\eric.bell\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2744, in __getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

The top is correct because it prints the data. (i narrowed it down for test purposes) and then there should be a graph, however i receive this error.

Thanks

Here is a sample of the data. 
I Took the original document and made a test one for me to work with, so this should be easier. For example, it only shows the first 11 rows and 28 columns.

In Blue are the X-Values and in Green are the Y- Values

In the Future I would like to have a second line in the graph with the same X-vales(Blue) and then the new Y-Values (Grey). However, lets solve the problem of it not graphing.

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORyVU.png)

Also here is a link to the 0Bin of the File.

https://0bin.net/paste/QxoRdHk013VLITGX#B8r36SH2Qw3dgds+gLKVI0ZsuxKMR0wCTL+7AbT-5rY

Thank you

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a sample of data from `CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv`, it would then be possible for us to recreate the problem.

Comment: Sure, I have now added a photo of the data.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like [0bin](https://0bin.net/) to upload the test file to, and then post a link to it here.

Comment: The Test file is only the data displayed in the photo i uploaded.However i will use 0bin to upload it as well.

Comment: It would save people having to manually try and enter all the data to be able to test your code.

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/QxoRdHk013VLITGX#B8r36SH2Qw3dgds+gLKVI0ZsuxKMR0wCTL+7AbT-5rY

Comment: I would upload the original so you can see how i compressed it, however it is too large for 0Bin. Thus, i think the Test Data Is sufficient to help me through this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that your data was being stored as `object` type. Converting to int seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.read_csv('CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv').T.to_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv', header=False)
df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv', skiprows=2)

plt.plot(df['SN'][16:21].astype(int))
plt.plot(df['26'][15:21].astype(int))
plt.show()
```

Giving you an output as:

[image: plot output]

Comment: That works thank you, however i Don't think i completely understand python. I am only trying to graph. 
X-Values : 35-39 (for the test values)
Y-Values : 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 etc until this values changes
Does this make sense?

I'm thinking that my script     [16:21] is the problem. I thought this would only pick numbers from those cells, however it does not look like this is the case

Comment: Ohh I just figured it out.  Thank you very Much! i do have another question of you are available please let me know. 

The solution was to combine the two:

    plt.plot(DID[16:21], Value[16:21].astype(int))

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Probably easiest to start a new SO question, then more people will see it.

Comment: Hello, if you have time, here is the link to my new problem . Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073778/choosing-the-correct-values-in-excel-in-python