# Choosing the correct values in excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot

General Overview:

I am creating a graph of a large data set, however i have created a sample text document so that it is easier to overcome the problems. 
The Data is from an excel document that will be saved as a CSV.

Problem:

I am able to compile the data a it will graph (see below) However how i pull the data will not work for all of the different excel sheet i am going to pull off of.

More Detail of problem:

The Y-Values (Labeled 'Value' and 'Value1') are being pulled for the excel sheet from the numbers 26 and 31 (See picture and Code). 
This is a problem because the Values 26 and 31 will not be the same for each graph.

Lets take a look for this to make more sense. 
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pd.read_csv('CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv').T.to_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv,header=False)

df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv', skiprows = 2)

DID = df['SN']
Value = df['26']

Value1 = df['31']


x= (DID[16:25])
y= (Value[16:25])
y1= (Value1[16:25])

"""
print(x,y)
print(x,y1)
"""

plt.plot(x.astype(int), y.astype(int))
plt.plot(x.astype(int), y1.astype(int))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Data Set:

[image: Data Set]

Below in the comments you will find the 0bin to my Data Set this is because i do not have enough reputation to post two links.

As you can see from the Data Set

```
 X- DID   = Blue 
 Y-Value  = Green 
 Y-Value1 = Grey 
Troublesome Values = Red
```

The problem again is that the data for the Y-Values are pulled from Row 10&11 from values 26,31 under SN

Let me know if more information is needed. 
Thank you

Comment: Here is the 0bin for my Data set. I do not have enough Reputation to post two links.

https://0bin.net/paste/QxoRdHk013VLITGX#B8r36SH2Qw3dgds+gLKVI0ZsuxKMR0wCTL+7AbT-5rY

Comment: Could you just access the values by their column number? e.g. `print pd.read_csv('CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv', skiprows=8).ix[:,19:]`

Comment: That is what i was wondering, i just did not know the syntax and could not find it on the website

Comment: So i am reading my transposed document. Thus my paramaters will be a bit off. however i stated

`df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Transpose_Test.csv', skiprows = 2).iii[:,9:]`

and it says object has no attribute 'iii' what should i put if i want it to look at row 3 cell 9 and on ward

Comment: Never mind, i fixed that problem. let me see what is output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are creating the transposed CSV version. It is also possible to work directly from your original data. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('CSV_GM_NB_Test.csv', skiprows=8)

data = df.ix[:,19:].T
data.columns = df['SN']
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

This would give you:

[image: plot screenshot]

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.ix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html#pandas-dataframe-ix) to give you a sliced version of your data using integer positions. The `[:,19:]` says to give you columns `19` onwards. The final `.T` transposes it. You can then apply the values for the `SN` column as column headings using `.columns` to specify the names.

Comment: Ohh, i didnt know that.

Comment: Thank you, 
Do you mind explaining the syntax of `.ix[:,19:].T`

Comment: Also, that is exactly what i need just on a larger scale. Would you mind if i uploaded the full document for you to look at and see if it is possible?

Comment: Here is the 0Bin for my final document. Is it possible to graph this data?
https://0bin.net/paste/YZDQIGLf1XGjRoVL#OcJu78cCWjL9I0SfmjnBCUI8q32qtn-9IlLVwC+ymnz

Comment: I don't think 0bin is fully compatible with zip files. I've not been able to extract it.

Comment: I don't believe it is a zip file. i will try it again.

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/W0BUzzIOs4-ouBVH#mLu7IuEtN2h+9xiNZ9p+tENLx2EgpNKos2KxKU17Gie

Comment: That works.... but it is not exactly clear what you are trying to graph. For example many SN entries have the same value.

Comment: Yes they will have the same value because it is all based on time and if they get recorded then they just go into the spreadsheet at that time. 
I would like to combine SN's and graph them. The purpose is for detecting faults very quickly> we know the values it should be so we would like to be able to look at a graph and be able to see a fault. and then zoom in on the line and see which SN it was and at what X-value it was at

Comment: I mean we dont need to combine SN values because it wont matter when looking at graph. but i was wondering if there was a way to label the line with the SN number, not put that in the legend.

Comment: For example, This is the code i have now that you showed me
`import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Replica_Test.csv', skiprows=8)

data = df.ix[:,19:116].T

data.columns=df['SN']
data.plot()
plt.show()`

Comment: You can turn the legend off using `ax = data.plot(legend=False)`. This also gives you `ax` which could be used to add annotation to the graph. You would need to decide how to annotate it though, for example `ax.annotate('SN=1234', xy=(63, 4.0), xytext=(45, 3.5), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.001, width=0.5, headwidth=4.0))`. I think the data needs work though before being plotted.